# How to SUM Table Column by UserID weekly and echo it out in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I need help to be able to sum "total_attendance table column" by user id  weekly starting from Sunday and echo it out.

This week's output should override last week's output, while next week's output should override this week's output on and on like that

Below is the code i already wrote for this

I got this error.

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in ….

Beyond the error, please i need a working code.

Thanks as always

```
<?php $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT SUM(totalattn) FROM 
attendance GROUP BY yearweek(date, 0) WHERE user_id='$user_id'");

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 $totalattn = $row['totalattn']; 
 echo $totalattn;
 }                            
?>
```

Comment: What's the mysql error?  use mysqli_error...

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/soap/attendance.php on line 214

Comment: That's the php error, look up the function I suggested

Answer (score 1):

The `GROUP BY` clause requires you specify the field by which to group as part of the `SELECT`clause.
Also, the `WHERE`clause needs to be placed before the `GROUP BY` clause

```
<?php $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT yearweek(date, 0), SUM(totalattn) FROM 
attendance  WHERE user_id='$user_id' GROUP BY yearweek(date, 0)");
```

Always follow this order:

```
SELECT something
FROM some place
JOIN with some other place
WHERE conditions are met
GROUP BY something you selected which you'd want to aggregate
```

Also, remember to escape your query to prevent injections and all kinds of nasty

Comment: `The GROUP BY clause requires you specify the field by which to group as part of the SELECTclause` Have any documentation for that?

Comment: @javier,  in order of yours, i reconstructed the query in this manner, yet i still got the same error. <?php $result1 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT SUM(totalattn) FROM attendance WHERE user_id='$user_id' GROUP BY yearweek(date, 0)");

Comment: @Devon That's generally an SQL requirement, although MySQL may not enforce it, depending on the version/mode. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html Still, without seeing the actual error, pointing to this as the cause seems a bit speculative. WHERE before GROUP BY, on the other hand...

Comment: No, you didn't add the most important part.. the `SELECT`clause must contain the field by which you intend to group... try `SELECT yearweek(date, 0), SUM(totalattn) FROM...` and group by yearkweek(date, 0)

Comment: Am i to group by column name? because i have date timestamp as a column?

Comment: You need to group by "something". Since your desired result is to get the SUM of `totalattn` by week, you need to have a column with the week to group by...

Comment: @JavierLarroulet I have reconstructed according to your last comment, i still got the same error.

Comment: what error are you getting from the mysql_server? (not the PHP error you quoted in the question)

Comment: @JavierLarroulet This is the error from mysql server: #1054 - Unknown column 'date' in 'field list'

Comment: My date column was attdate but now i have changed it to date, i no longer get that error. Thanks for that clue @JavierLarroulet. But now i get this error: Notice: Undefined index: totalattn in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/soap/attendance.php on line 215

Comment: that means 'totalattn' is not an index for the `$row` array.. Since you're using `while` you need to specify the index with a control variable (you may define $i = 0 before entering the while loop, change `$row['totalattn']` to `$row[$i]['totalattn']` and increment $i by 1 right after echoing. If all else fails, try outputting the whole array with print_r so you can see the exact array structure and indexes so you know the exact way to access the data

Comment: @JavierLarroulet. With your help, i was able to solve the problem. it works now. Thanks a lot.